# Wine-Staging Broken Packages in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine

I'm able to install `wine` just fine, but get an error when I try to install `wine-staging`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 4.16~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: remove all Wine packages and reinstall.  Known issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem in dependencies wine-staging needs

```
Depends: libfaudio0 but it is not installable
```

This package is not available in ubuntu. I run in the same error.

you can try the package  [from this source](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/amd64/libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_amd64.deb)

```
sudo dpkg --simulate -i libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_amd64.deb
```

If no error accure remove `--simulate` from my command
I'm not able to test because of my 32-bit system.